# Writing a faster function to find the inverse of 3x3 matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-inverse

Working with R and linear algebra, I wrote the following function which appears to be faster than other R functions, to find the inverse of a 3x3 matrix (basically based on Adjugate Matrix and determinants method), without the use of precompiled functions like `det()`.

Here is the code:

```R
invert_matrix3x3 <- function(a) {
  if (is.matrix(a) != T) stop("The input is not a matrix")
  if (ncol(a) != nrow(a)) stop("The matrix is not a square matrix")
  if (ncol(a)!=3 | nrow(a)!=3) stop("The matrix is not a 3x3 matrix")
  b <- matrix(rep(0,9), ncol=3)
  det1a <- (a[1,3]*a[2,2]*a[3,1] - a[1,2]*a[2,3]*a[3,1] - a[1,3]*a[2,1]*a[3,2] + a[1,1]*a[2,3]*a[3,2] + a[1,2]*a[2,1]*a[3,3] - a[1,1]*a[2,2]*a[3,3])
  det2a <- -det1a
  if (det1a == 0) stop("The matrix is singular and not invertible")
  numb11 <- (a[2,3]*a[3,2] - a[2,2]*a[3,3])
  numb21 <- (a[2,1]*a[3,3] - a[2,3]*a[3,1])
  numb31 <- (a[2,1]*a[3,2] - a[2,2]*a[3,1])
  b[1,1] <- numb11 / det1a
  b[2,1] <- numb21 / det1a
  b[3,1] <- numb31 / det2a
  numb12 <- (a[1,3]*a[3,2] - a[1,2]*a[3,3])
  numb22 <- (a[1,3]*a[3,1] - a[1,1]*a[3,3])
  numb32 <- (a[1,1]*a[3,2] - a[1,2]*a[3,1])
  b[1,2] <- numb12 / det2a
  b[2,2] <- numb22 / det1a
  b[3,2] <- numb32 / det1a
  numb13 <- (a[1,3]*a[2,2] - a[1,2]*a[2,3])
  numb23 <- (a[1,1]*a[2,3] - a[1,3]*a[2,1])
  numb33 <- (a[1,1]*a[2,2] - a[1,2]*a[2,1])
  b[1,3] <- numb13 / det1a
  b[2,3] <- numb23 / det1a
  b[3,3] <- numb33 / det2a
  return(b)
}
```

And here is the computation time, compared with other known function:

```R
a <- matrix(c(5, 1, 0, 3,-1, 2, 4, 0,-1), nrow=3, byrow=TRUE) 
require(MASS)
require(pracma)

all.equal(inv(a), ginv(a))
all.equal(ginv(a), solve(a))
all.equal(solve(a), invert_matrix3x3(a))

system.time(replicate(100000, ginv(a)))
   user  system elapsed 
  3.724   0.040   3.779 

system.time(replicate(100000, inv(a)))
   user  system elapsed 
  2.655   0.014   2.687 

system.time(replicate(100000, solve(a)))
   user  system elapsed 
  1.722   0.007   1.737 

system.time(replicate(100000, invert_matrix3x3(a)))
   user  system elapsed 
  1.112   0.006   1.124
```

- Is my methods to estimate the computation times correct?
- Do you you believe there may be further improvements to the code?
- Do you think it is worth to create a similar function for 4x4 matrix?

### EDIT

thanks to the [@r2evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3358272/r2evans) comment, here is the boxplot comparison using `microbenchmark`:

```
require(microbenchmark)
boxplot(microbenchmark(invert_matrix3x3(a), inv(a), ginv(a), solve(a), times=1000L))
```

[image: boxplot]

Comment: Not answering your question but related. R has the nice library Rcpp to use C++ within R. It will probably help if you need speed.

Comment: Your use of `replicate(10000,..)` and `system.time` are one way; other ways include `bench::mark` and `microbenchmark::microbenchmark`, which provide side-by-side comparisons of times (and other metrics), taking into account garbage-collection (which can skew results) and other things.

Comment: I'd guess the effect would be small but you could replace the nine divides by one divide and nine multiplies if you store eg 1.0/det1a and multiply by that rather than dividing by det1a. Divides can be significantly slower then multiplies.

Comment: Another possible, small, optimisation would be to compute the determinant of the matrix by a laplace expansion rather than directly. Since you are already calculating the determinants of each of the 2x2 matrices, you could use these to reduce the calculation of the overall determinant to 3 multiplies and an add and a subtract, instead of the 12 multiplies and 5 add/subtracts